# office365 ActiveDirectory v 3.10 not deserializing tokencacheobject saved by ActiveDirectory v 2.24

Tags: office365, adal, azure-active-directory

I have just updated ActiveDirectory Version from 2.24 to 3.10 but after this change i started getting exception ***"Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"***

If i check the same object over old dll it deserializes the tokens. Please suggest if i need to modify my code to get tokens deserialize via new DLL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

V3 Cache is a different format and cannot be deserialzed using a v2 object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any resource where we can verify the compatibly of new version with old version.

Comment: Another quick question, is there any way to migrate old tokenscache object with new one so that new dll can use it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "any resource". User would need to reauthenticate if using v3 and once that is done, everything would work as expected.

Comment: "any resource" means any document online that contains details about new changes in version 3.10. Such as release notes or change logs.

Comment: Changes and fixes are a part of the changelog in github.